# Websphere can't find my Hibernate-managed EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, spring, openjpa, websphere-7

I'm using Hibernate 3.4 on Websphere 7, with Spring 2.5.6

On startup, my application seems to have problems with Hibernate vs. OpenJPA:

```
10/02/12 10:41:50:448 GMT] 00000010 LocalEntityMa I org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory Building JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mypu'
[10/02/12 10:41:50:495 GMT] 00000010 SystemErr     R   WARNING: Found unrecognized persistence provider "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" in place of OpenJPA provider.  This provider's properties will not be used.
```

... and then a lovely stack trace caused by:

> PersistenceProvider [org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl@6b676b67] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'mypu'

For info, my persistence unit is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="mypu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/serviceTrackerDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>...my classes...</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate & Derby -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="APP"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. It seems like the wrong persistence provider is being used somewhere, but I have specified the correct provider in persistence.xml. I know that OpenJPA is the default persistence manager in Websphere 7, but I'd like to use Hibernate here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I needed to add a `jpaVendorAdapter` to my `entityManagerFactory`.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mypu" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Still testing but looks good as a resolution.