# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to deploy an application in the following environment.

- JPA 2.0
- Spring 3.2.2
- MySQL 5.6.11

My configurations until now in the `application-context.xml` file are as under.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="WebAppPU"/>
        <!--<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>-->
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="testDAOService" class="admin.dao.TestDAO"/>
</beans>
```

This works fine until the commented lines in the above xml file are uncommented. When these lines are uncommented, I'm getting the following exception.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#932760' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#932760' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#932760' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 67 more
```

I have tried to add `hibernate-entity-manger-4.2.0.jar` to the classpath but that caused another exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException`.

So, which jar files are needed exactly here? Is it dependent upon the Hibernate framework which I'm not using in this application?

---

The `persistence.xml` file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Test</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_networking?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

**Update :**

**Quick reply :** (as the answers below do not directly address the cause of the exception)

The cause of the stated exception was (most probably) that I misconfigured `databasePlatform` as `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` in the given XML file though I was using MySQL 5.x.

It should have actually been `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` instead (or version-restricted/version-specific - `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`).

**Disclaimer :** I do not remember precisely the exact cause of the exception after more than one year but most probably (99.99%) this misconfiguration was the culprit.

Comment: Tiny, I have a similar error, not sure what causes this error! http://stackoverflow.com/q/27293726/599528

Comment: Sorry, I went through the post but I did not get cause of the exception. As to this question, I myself cannot remember precisely what changes actually made it work. I did not answer myself here, since I did not much respond to the community as I was very new to this field at the time of this post.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you look at **spring-orm** maven dependency you will see that it depends on **hibernate-entitymanager** which is the jar that contains the class not found.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.1.RELEASE

Add those dependencies to your maven configuration file.

Comment: I have already tried adding `hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.jar` but didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: When I added **only** `hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.jar`, I got this exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException`.

Comment: I have now added I have added these jar files to the classpath as the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427511/1391249) provided by Templar indicates : `cglib-2.1.3.jar`, `hibernate-c3p0-4.2.0.CR1.jar`, `hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar`, `javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar` and `hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar`. This caused [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate](http://pastebin.com/9g9QKLqE).

Comment: this is a pain the ass, but if you look here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.2.RELEASE you will see that you should use hibernate-core-3.2.2, because the 4.2.0 doesnt have the EntityNotFoundDelegate class

Comment: I have just added all jar files supplied in Hibernate 3.2.5 (which I was using earlier) and I got an additional exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence@1803041] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'WebAppPU'`. I have the same configuration as mentioned by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9226880/1391249) answer though.

Comment: Solved my case by upgrading spring-orm from a 3.X version to a 4.X version. i.e. no longer rely on version using HibernatePersistence class.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the directory:

C:\Users\${user}.m2\repository\org\hibernate\

and installing the again did the trick for me.

The HibernateException was just missing and therefore a linkt to hibernate-entitymanager or the maven repo was corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using HibernateTemplate you need to use Hibernate 3.*

Otherwise you can use Hibernate 4.*

Librarys:

- org.springframework.spring-orm
- cglib
- org.hibernate.hibernate-core
- org.hibernate-c3p0
- javaassist

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.patrickgotthard</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not using Hibernate anymore still these jar files needed? And `pom.xml` should be unnecessary, since this is not a maven project.

Comment: There are no jars for jpa. Hibernate is just like EclipseLink or OpenJPA a JPA provider that means you need one of them to use JPA. I just included this pom.xml so you can quickly download these jars.

Comment: I have added these jar files to the classpath `cglib-2.1.3.jar`, `hibernate-c3p0-4.2.0.CR1.jar`, `hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar`, `javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar` and `hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar`. This caused [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate](http://pastebin.com/9g9QKLqE). Tried to search in Google but didn't find.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate has a [whole mess of dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.2.0.Final) that are best addressed using [maven](http://maven.apache.org), [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy), or some other java dependency manager. You appear to be using the Hibernate ORM adapter for [Spring](http://www.springsource.org).